# How do I make a clickable signs set a block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a command where there is a clickable sign that teleports a player to spawn. Here is the command:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:wall_sign 2 replace {Text1:"{text:\"Start\",clickEvent:{action:run_command,value:\"/tp @p[c=1] -658 104 -690\"}}"}
```

How do I alter the command to setblock a redstone block?

I tried this:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:wall_sign 2 replace {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Set Gamemodes\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/setblock -44 110 248 152 delete\"}}"}
```

but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you currently using?

Comment: I'm using Minecraft 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 1.7, you can no longer refer to a block by its numeric Block ID; instead you must use its full name. Thus, you should replace `152` with `redstone_block`.

Also, with `/setblock`, you need to specify the `[dataValue]` before you can specify the `[oldBlockHandling]` mode, so you should add a `0` before `delete`.

Fixed command should look like:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:wall_sign 2 replace {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Set Gamemodes\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/setblock -44 110 248 redstone_block 0 delete\"}}"}
```

---

In situations like this where you're setting signs that execute commands or have nested execute commands, I often find it useful to "unwrap" it and try each layer of command separately.

For example, you can try the innermost command (`/setblock -44 110 248 152 delete`) in chat or a command block to get a somewhat useful message that can help you with fixing the first error:

```
There is no such block with name minecraft:152
```